# Why the emphasis of unblemished offerings only in Numbers 28:31

Tags: law, hebrew-bible, moses, torah

After reminding Israel of the offerings they had to do on a daily, monthly, and annual basis in [Numbers 28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=numbers%2028&version=NKJV), it's only in verse 31 that the author mentions the quality of offerings needed:

"Be sure they are without blemish. You shall present them with their drink offerings, besides the regular burnt offering with its grain offering."

How come this emphasis was only in the portion of the Feast of Weeks offerings? Is there particular importance to the Feast of Weeks?

Comment: EVERY sacrifice in this and the next chapter of Numbers 28 & 29 must be unblemished.  This is an ill-conceived question.  There is no emphasis on the feats of weeks or any other festival - all require unblemished animals.